# How to add an extra button in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

To clarify this, I don't want to add a new activity or custom button to share.
I want to add a new action button as the `Cancel` option. See attached file.

[image]

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` like this.

```
UIActivityViewController * avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:shareItems applicationActivities:nil];
NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypePrint,
                               UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                               UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                               UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];

avc.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;
[avc setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(UIActivityType  _Nullable activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray * _Nullable returnedItems, NSError * _Nullable activityError) {
    //something
}];
[self presentViewController:avc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The idea is add an extra button, for example `Done` button

Comment: Can't be done. There is no API to tailor a `UIActivityViewController` except for adding custom activities.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @rmaddy do you have any documentation where confirm that info?

Comment: Sure. Look at the reference documentation for UIActivyViewController.